# Grafana with aws elasticsearch data source not working in phantomjs

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, phantomjs, grafana

I'm using grafana 5.1.3. My data source is aws elasticsearch. I'm using API request and creating a **snapshot URL**. When I render that URL in phantomjs it shows me an error page. Same URL if I load in chrome/Mozilla browser it works fine. Also if I have any local elasticsearch data source, phantom rendering works fine. I don't know why the issue occurs only with aws elasticsearch. Meanwhile, I checked in puppeteer too. Still the same issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we try to authenticate the grafana thro headers in phantomjs, the request to the datasource(aws) is block for security reasons. If we login directly to the login form, it will work.